# How can I prove this double sum equation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, modular-forms, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to prove that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{n^2x^2-m^2}{(m^2+n^2x^2)^2}=-\frac{\pi}{2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{n^2x^2-m^2}{\left(m^2+n^2/x^2\right)^2}$$
I'm missing $-\frac{\pi}{2x}$ in my process, just by swapping $n\to m,\, m\to n$ in sum above on LHS as follows:
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{n^2x^2-m^2}{(m^2+n^2x^2)^2}&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{m^2x^2-n^2}{(n^2+m^2x^2)^2}\\
&=-\frac1{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{n^2/x^2-m^2}{(m^2+n^2~/x^2)^2}\end{align*}$$
Here I see that the exchange of summation operators probably cannot be applied, but I can't see that. Any help will be welcome!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this style of problem. It looks to me that $\sum_{n=1} \sum_{m=1} \frac{n^2}{(m^2+n^2)^2}$ weakly diverges by power-counting. Is it a-priori obvious that $\sum_{n=1} \sum_{m=1} \frac{x^2 n^2-m^2}{(m^2+x^2 n^2)^2}$ converges? Also, how should I interpret the equality you give when $x=1$: it seems to say $0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @user196574 For $x=1$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{n^2-m^2}{(m^2+n^2)^2}=-\frac\pi 4$

Comment: Whoops, I was thinking that sum would be zero, but that was my mistake. I'm gaining appreciation for these types of sums.

Answer (score 2):

The sum doesn't converge **absolutely**, so you can't simply rearrange it.

The equality itself holds for $x>0$, and is the particular case (at $z=ix$) of the following fact (known as a property of the so-called *non-holomorphic* [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) $G_2$):

> For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Im z>0$, and for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, define $$f_{m,n}(z)=\begin{cases}\hfill 0,\hfill&(m,n)=(0,0)\\(m+nz)^{-2},&\hfill\text{otherwise}\hfill\end{cases},\\F(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}f_{m,n}(z),\qquad\overline{F}(z)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f_{m,n}(z).$$ Then $F(z)-\overline{F}(z)=2\pi i/z$.

Here is the most elementary proof I know. Define, a similar way, $$g_{m,n}(z)=\begin{cases}\hfill 0,\hfill&(m,n)\in\big\{(0,0),(1,0)\big\}\\(m-1+nz)^{-1}-(m+nz)^{-1},&\hfill\text{otherwise}\hfill\end{cases},\\G(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}g_{m,n}(z),\qquad\overline{G}(z)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}g_{m,n}(z).$$

Then $F(z)-G(z)=\overline{F}(z)-\overline{G}(z)$ since **this time** we have absolute convergence.

Further, it's easy to see that $G(z)=2$ identically; indeed $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}g_{m,n}(z)$ is a telescoping sum, which vanishes if $n\neq 0$, and equals $2$ if $n=0$.

The sum $\overline{G}(z)$ is also a telescoping one, but a bit harder (for me). Using the [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{z+n}+\frac1{z-n}\right)=\pi\cot\pi z-\frac1z\qquad(z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z})$$ we find $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}g_{m,n}(z)=\begin{cases}\hfill 1-\frac{\pi}{z}\cot\frac{\pi}{z},\hfill&m\in\{0,1\}\\\frac{\pi}{z}\left(\cot\pi\frac{m-1}{z}-\cot\pi\frac{m}{z}\right),&\hfill\text{otherwise}\hfill\end{cases}.$$

Since $\Im z>0$, we have $\lim\limits_{m\to\pm\infty}\cot(\pi m/z)=\pm i$. Thus, summing the above over $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$\overline{G}(z)=\frac{\pi}z\left(-i-\cot\frac{-\pi}z\right)+2\left(1-\frac{\pi}z\cot\frac{\pi}z\right)+\frac{\pi}z\left(\cot\frac{\pi}z-i\right)=2-\frac{2\pi i}z,$$ and the desired result follows.

Comment: Very interesting, although I didn't understand the proof essentially.  I was more relaxed with the phrase: "The sum doesn't converge absolutely, so you can't simply rearrange it."  Thank you!

Comment: @lpb: Too concise perhaps. I just didn't want to make the proof unnecessarily long and "polluted" with obvious details. The key idea is to "approximate" $f_{m,n}$ by $g_{m,n}$, so that $\sum_{m,n}(f_{m,n}-g_{m,n})$ converges absolutely (therefore admits any rearrangement) and $\sum_{m}\sum_{n}g_{m,n}$ as well as $\sum_{n}\sum_{m}g_{m,n}$ are relatively easy to compute explicitly. (A "telescoping sum" is something like $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(a_{n-1}-a_n)$. What does it evaluate to?..) Anyway, feel free to make me clarify anything specific.

Comment: +1 there. I never tried the double sum thing for $G_2$ because of the non-absolute convergence.